# Index out of bound exception with inputstream data

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, java-io, stringbuffer

I was trying to flush data in a file in my local machine to response. But at some point I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = -1;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 4096)) != -1) {
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
inputStream.close();
outStream.close();
```

The above code is what I was trying. The `downloadFile` path given is correct and it works till the `while` loop. But then the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs. I tried it with `inputStream.read(buffer)` but that didn't work.

Comment: which line causes the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? The `read`?

Comment: yes..the inputstream.read. It doesnt enter the loop

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace.

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
 at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
 at com.cirakas.ilids.base.controller.dashboard.Controller.download(Controller.java:286)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
Cannot paste the complete stacktrace

Comment: `reader` code works ok in my computer....

Comment: @LEKSHMISURESH edit the question, don't paste extra info in comments

Comment: Have you looked at using IOUtils or similar package to copy between streams ? The copy method provides you options to copy from a Input Stream to an output writer. More precisely for you , the input is a  FileInputStream and the output is a response writer (Print writer may be i think)  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.Writer,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: The code you posted does not throw this exception. However you would be better off using `read(byte[])` rather than `read(byte[], int, int)`, as the latter only gives you a pointless opportunity to get the length wrong in this case, which is undoubtedly what happened in the real code you didn't post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give code is working perfectlly; since there is no information is given regarding the `response` object I have modify the `OutputStream` to `FileOutputStream`; just to test.

Below code segment is working perfectly.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\readme.txt");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\readme1.txt");
        //OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 4096)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```